# waitpid() gives incorrect exit code

Tags: c++, linux

I've got a function for starting a process, and then returning the stdout and exit code. However I've noticed that it claims that every process returns the exit code of 1. I control the executable being invoked and I had it print to stdout the exit code, so I've confirmed that when it "failed", it in fact returned 0 from `main`. I also invoked the executable directly form the shell and confirmed the expected stdout and exit code (0). So the fault must lie on the side of the caller. I've also confirmed that WIFEXITED doesn't return false- it returns true as if the child had exited normally (which it did).

This code worked fine before I needed to capture stdout, so it must have something to do with that. I tried looking into the "Child has already terminated" jobby, but that's not occurring in this case- waitpid() behaves exactly like I'd expect and just doesn't care that the child might have already terminated whilst I was nomming up the stdout.

```
#include <unistd.h>    
#include <sys/types.h>    
#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <iostream>

Wide::Driver::ProcessResult Wide::Driver::StartAndWaitForProcess(std::string name, std::vector<std::string> args, Util::optional<unsigned> timeout) {
    int filedes[2];
    pipe(filedes);


    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        while ((dup2(filedes[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1) && (errno == EINTR)) {}
        freopen("/dev/null", "rw", stdin);
        freopen("/dev/null", "rw", stderr);
        //close(filedes[0]);

        std::vector<const char*> cargs;

        cargs.push_back(name.c_str());

        for (auto&& arg : args)

            cargs.push_back(arg.c_str());

        cargs.push_back(nullptr);

        execv(name.c_str(), const_cast<char* const*>(&cargs[0]));

    }
    std::string std_out;
    close(filedes[1]);
    char buffer[4096];
    while (1) {
        ssize_t count = read(filedes[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (count == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                continue;
            } else {
                perror("read");
                exit(1);
            }
        } else if (count == 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            std_out += std::string(buffer, buffer + count);
        }
    }
    close(filedes[0]);

    int status;
    ProcessResult result;
    result.std_out = std_out;
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

    if (!WIFEXITED(status))

        result.exitcode = 1;

    else {
        result.exitcode = WEXITSTATUS(status);
        if (result.exitcode != 0) {
            std::cout << name << " failed with code " << result.exitcode << "\n";
            std::cout << "stdout: " << result.std_out;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Why on earth is waitpid() giving me this strange result and how can I fix it?

Comment: The exit code of the executed process resides within the text of `std_out`, not `result.exitcode`. The printing branch is never executed if `WIFEXITED(status)` is false anyway, so it would be impossible for me to print out the result of that assignment.

Comment: This looks quite suspicious `const_cast<char* const*>(&cargs[0])`

Comment: Not sure why the arguments should be mutable to execve, but I'm replacing the process anyway so I don't care about the memory state of the vector.

Comment: The second argument to `execv` is supposed to be a C array of strings. You're passing a pointer to the first item in a `std::vector`, this won't work when `execv` tries to access the arguments.

Comment: Get rid of the `stderr` redirection, so you'll see any error messages printed by the program.

Comment: @Barmar: A std::vector's items are an array. `execv` will get exactly what it's expecting- an array of C strings. I know that the called program doesn't write anything useful to stderr, although frankly I don't know why it would matter since I know for certain that it does, in fact, return 0.

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/174f244ad607cf0e

Comment: Not sure if it is reproducible with an online compiler. The exact behaviour likely depends on the characteristics of the process you're running.

Comment: I can. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d10f7c48ae17e4b I have a horrible, horrible feeling that it's actually the stderr redirection. I redirected that shit because LLVM dumps a bunch of noise there, but perhaps if they can't dump noise there, they exit the process with a code of 1?

Comment: If I don't redirect stderr to /dev/null, the problem goes away (albeit replaced with a new one). So I think that LLVM just goes crazy.

Comment: If it's dependent on the called code, you may want to [include](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it in the question. Wrt checking what LLVM does: You could start the program with redirection, attach `strace` to it, do the same without redirection, and then compare the system calls done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've confirmed in IRC that it is an LLVM issue. The exit code for the process I printed out is what I returned from `main`- a static destructor or other such code can still run and call `exit(1)`. This is caused by redirecting stderr- so basically you can't get the error, since if you don't redirect stderr you don't see the problem. So if you execute from the shell, since stderr is not redirected, it's all good.

Therefore, despite the shell and my own return code agreeing, the process was in fact returning the exit code of 1.

Apparently the issue is resolved in trunk, or should be, but I am still using 3.6.